# How to query key values from a hash of arrays of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have a JSONB payload in my database. This payload is from a GraphQL query of the shopify_api.

For the shop_order below, I am trying to query for the name of the fourth order in the node.

```
shop_order = {"data":{"orders":{"edges":[{"node":{"id":"gid://shopify/Order/2228134674512","name":"#1001","createdAt":"2020-05-01T18:46:04Z","shippingAddress":{"address1":"1234 Long Avenue, 2N","address2":"","city":"Chicago","province":"Illinois","provinceCode":"IL","zip":"55555"}}},{"node":{"id":"gid://shopify/Order/2239643451472","name":"#1002","createdAt":"2020-05-05T14:40:36Z","shippingAddress":{"address1":"1234 Long Avenue","address2":"2N","city":"Chicago","province":"Illinois","provinceCode":"IL","zip":"55555"}}},{"node":{"id":"gid://shopify/Order/2239950323792","name":"#1003","createdAt":"2020-05-05T16:35:38Z","shippingAddress":{"address1":"1234 Long Avenue","address2":"2N","city":"Chicago","province":"Illinois","provinceCode":"IL","zip":"55555"}}},{"node":{"id":"gid://shopify/Order/2239959105616","name":"#1004","createdAt":"2020-05-05T16:38:27Z","shippingAddress":{"address1":"1234 Long Avenue","address2":"2N","city":"Chicago","province":"Illinois","provinceCode":"IL","zip":"55555"}}}]}},"casted_data":{},"errors":[]}

order = shop_order[:data][:orders][:edges][3]
puts order

response > {:node=>{:id=>"gid://shopify/Order/2239959105616", :name=>"#1004", :createdAt=>"2020-05-05T16:38:27Z", :shippingAddress=>{:address1=>"1234 Long Avenue", :address2=>"2N", :city=>"Chicago", :province=>"Illinois", :provinceCode=>"IL", :zip=>"55555"}}}

order_to_a = shop_order[:data][:orders][:edges][3].to_a
puts order_to_a

response > node
{:id=>"gid://shopify/Order/2239959105616", :name=>"#1004", :createdAt=>"2020-05-05T16:38:27Z", :shippingAddress=>{:address1=>"1234 Long Avenue", :address2=>"2N", :city=>"Chicago", :province=>"Illinois", :provinceCode=>"IL", :zip=>"55555"}}
```

How do I query and display a specific value from a key that is inside a node?

Comment: It's not apparent why this is difficult. Do the same thing using Hash's `[]` accessors. Why is this a PostgreSQL question? What in the question refers to PgSQL or implicates it? The same is true of SQL and Rails or Graphql. Tags are for things that are immediately tied to the code or problem, not  things that are part of a system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what your intent is, but your access of elements in a hash can be streamlined using `dig`:

```
shop_order = { 
  "data": { 
    "orders": { 
      "edges": [
        {}, {}, {}, { 
          "node": { 
            "name": '#1004', 
            "shippingAddress": { 
              "zip": '55555' 
            } 
          } 
        }
      ] 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Access data using:

```
order = shop_order.dig(:data, :orders, :edges)[3]
# => {:node=>{:name=>"#1004", :shippingAddress=>{:zip=>"55555"}}}
```

or:

```
order = shop_order.dig(:data, :orders, :edges, 3)
# => {:node=>{:name=>"#1004", :shippingAddress=>{:zip=>"55555"}}}
```

> How do I query and display a specific value from a key that is inside a node?

Huh? If you want information inside `order`, do the same sort of thing:

```
order.dig(:node, :name) # => "#1004"
order.dig(:node, :shippingAddress, :zip) # => "55555"
```

or:

```
shop_order.dig(:data, :orders, :edges, 3, :node, :name) # => "#1004"
shop_order.dig(:data, :orders, :edges, 3, :node, :shippingAddress, :zip) # => "55555"
```

Many times when we're walking through a complex hash of arrays we point to the array in a variable and then work from that point. It's similar to putting your finger on a page in a recipe, so we can go back to it quickly. We do the same when parsing HTML/XML, parsed JSON and YAML, etc.

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation and the help.

Comment: No problem. Please notice how I reduced your hash definition down to just enough to demonstrate the problem and solution. That's an important part of asking a question, reduction of the code and input data. When you do it often it will help you find the problem in the process of doing it. And, that also helps us see problems quickly so you don't have to wait as long a time to get a solution. It's a cooperative venture, you're helping us help you.

Comment: Absolutely. And I appreciated how you simply demonstrated the problem/solution concisely. There is more that I am doing with this data, but this set me on the correct path.

Comment: That's just what we do here. It's repaying the community for what we learned in the past, and giving you information so you can pay it forward when you are in a position to do so.